# Prove the inequality $e^x \geq 1+\ln(x+1)$ where $x\geq-1$

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

How can I prove $e^x\geq1+\ln(x+1)$ for $x>-1$?
I was thinking about Bernoulli's inequality or derivatives, but I cannot move forward.
Will be very thankful for help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/27793#27793) is a MathJax tutorial.  Equality holds when $x=0$ and $e^x$ is concave upward and $1+\ln(x+1)$ is concave downward

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Hint :** Prove $e^x \geq x+1 \geq 1+\ln(x+1)$.

Comment: Hint: change the goal to $e^x-1\ge\ln(x+1)$, and notice that the two sides are inverse functions of each other. (Note that this is really @TheSilverDoe's hint in disguise.)

Comment: Actually, the assertion as stated is false, because the function $\ln(x+1)$ is not defined at $x = -1.$  So, the range of the assertion should be changed from $x \color{red}{\geq} -1$ to $x \color{blue}{>} -1.$

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x-x-1$$

has a single minimum at $x=0$, with value $0$. So

$$e^x\ge x+1$$

Then taking the logarithm (a strictly growing function), for $x+1>0$

$$x\ge\log(x+1)$$

and combining,

$$e^x\ge x+1\ge\log(x+1)+1.$$

Answer (score -1):

As it is, the problem is ill-posed since for the value $x=-1$ we can't define $\ln(x+1)$. But if we allow $x\gt-1$ it is valid.

A direct approach:

Let $f(x)=e^x-\ln(x+1)-1$ for $x\in (-1, +\infty]$.

It is easy to see that $f$ is differentiable.

Now we are trying to discern the monotonicity of $f$ by examining $f'$.

We have: $$f'(x)=e^x-\frac1{x+1}$$

Since we can't obtain a direct result we further differentiate $f'$.

$$f''(x)=e^x+\frac1{(x+1)^2}\gt0 \forall x \in (-1, +\infty]$$

So, $f'$ is strictly increasing $\forall x \in (-1, +\infty]$

Thus if $x\in (-1,0]\Rightarrow f'(x)\lt f'(0)=0$.

So $f$ is strictly decreasing for $x\in (-1,0]$.

Similarly we can show that f is strictly increasing for $x\in [0, +\infty]$.

So $\forall x \in (-1,0]\Rightarrow f(x)>f(0)=0$ and $\forall x \in [0,+\infty]\Rightarrow f(x)>f(0)=0$ which provides the result.

Comment: Your second derivative expression is wrong

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you for noticing. Corrected.

Comment: May the downvoter care to explain his reasoning?